# Jenkins remote deploy

Tags: node.js, jenkins, bitbucket, continuous-deployment

I am trying to implement Jenkins for automating the deployment of a node application.

I am really new to this Jenkins setup. In my case, I have one server for Jenkins. I created a freestyle project in Jenkins and configured bitbucket and scm polling. It works perfectly.

But now Jenkins is deploying to the Jenkins server itself. But I need to deploy this to another remote server.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To build jobs on remote host, you need to perform below steps:

1. Add node:

   - Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes > New Node.

The next step is to set the node name and then you will be asked for remote server details.
After clicking the save button it should try to launch the slave machine.

Reference:
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/227834227-How-to-create-a-new-node-

2. Mention newly created node into your job configuration:

   - Set the "Restrict where this job can be run" check box in your job configuration and specify the name of your slave (which you have mentioned in step 1)

Comment: I'll try this one.